# sublime text3 clang-format fatal error: 'iostream' file not found

Tags: c++, sublimetext3, clang-format

When I use *clang-format* to format my C++ code in sublime text3,  I received that error `iostream file not found`.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, const char *argv[]) {
    cout << "HELLO, Captain Teemo!" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

[image]

But I can run the c++ code with Command+B.

[image]

I also can compile the c++ code in command line.

[image]

Comment: Are you sure that the error is coming from clang-format? It seems strange that a formatting tool parses includes and other C++ identifiers. Maybe the message comes from another sublime package, for example, EasyClangComplete?

Comment: Sorry, I found that not the clang-format but the clang-complete plugin cause the error!

Comment: Okay. The EasyClangComplete allows you to specify the include paths, see https://github.com/niosus/EasyClangComplete#3-configure-your-includes

Comment: Thank you very much@pschill , I installed ClangComplete and AutoClangComplete. But I only specify the AutoClangComplete paths, not specify the ClangComplete paths.I have removed ClangComplete package.

Comment: @P.Cheng I recommend to install a *single* plugin for completion. Your example should work out of the box in EasyClangComplete